# Why Atom can search only in file but not in project for regex newline?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

Like imgs below, I want to find and replace something in my markdown files. When I am in file panel, it's ok to find, but if I try to find in project folder, it fails. I searched the Atom help but found nothing useful.

find in file:

https://github.com/jetorz/DongTalks.com/blob/master/fine-in-file.png

find in project:

https://github.com/jetorz/DongTalks.com/blob/master/find-in-project.png

How can I find these items in project so I can replace them in batch? There are hundreds files, so it is too much troublesome to do it one by one.

Comment: Your first image shows that your search is not working in file find mode either.

Comment: I was strange about that too. The search result shows that no result was found, but the editor window highlight what I wanted to get. I was confused about that too...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the carriage return is missing.

Try with:

```
category: "Card"\r\n
```

or in extremis:

```
category: "Card"\s
```

See [regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html)